# how to condition a url depending on the parameters in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I currently have my site like this:

```
@main.route("/reports", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reports():
return render_template(
"template.html")
```

I intend to add a new design and place it in the following way if in the url they add "/reports/1" or "/reports/0" direct them to a different template:

```
@main.route("/reports/<int:ds>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
 def reports(ds):
  View=ds
  if View == 1:
   return render_template("template.html")
  if View == 0:
   return render_template("templateNew.html")
```

Within templeteNew.html I have the option to return to my old layout and place it in the same way by sending a parameter

```
<a href="{{ url_for('main.report_in', ds=1) }}" >
  Return to previous layout
</a>
```

The problem is that in the whole project and in external projects it refers to this url:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/reportes
```

and it might cause errors if I implement it the way I intended. What I want is that if there is any other way to condition the url, if they write this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/reportes
```

I directed them to this:

```
@main.route("/reports/<int:ds>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reports(ds):
     View=ds
if View == 1:
    return render_template(
         "template.html")
if View == 0:
    return render_template(
         "templateNew.html")
```

Any suggestions to improve this please?

Answer (score 0):

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/reportes` looks like a typo (extra "e").

Anyway you can add one more `route` to your function as follows:

```
@main.route("/reports", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@main.route("/reports/<int:ds>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reports(ds=1):  # <-- provide here the default value you want ds to be
     View=ds
if View == 1:
    return render_template(
         "template.html")
if View == 0:
    return render_template(
         "templateNew.html")
```

Another option is to pass the default value in the route definition:

```
@main.route("/reports", methods=["GET", "POST"], defaults={'ds': 1})
@main.route("/reports/<int:ds>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def reports(ds): to be
     View=ds
if View == 1:
    return render_template(
         "template.html")
if View == 0:
    return render_template(
         "templateNew.html")
```